# Simple sharer.php doesn't work for each URL and share_count stays to zero

Tags: api, count, share, facebook-sharer

I needed a very simple solution to share a page on Facebook. I found this code here :

daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-create-a-custom-facebook-share-button-with-a-custom-counter

It works very well except on some pages where share_count never increment even thought page is successfully shared on profile.

However, i use exactly the same code to share :

```
<a title="Share on Facebook" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=Buzz+et+Woody+pour+son+bapt%C3%AAme&amp;p[summary]=Organisation+du+bapt%C3%AAme+du+petit+L%C3%A9o+par+Les+cr%C3%A2neuses.+Un+event+design+autour+de+Buzz+et+Woody.&amp;p[url]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.les-craneuses.fr%2Fbuzz-et-woody-pour-son-bapteme%2F&amp;&amp;p[images][0]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.les-craneuses.fr%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F05%2FDSC_0096-300x199.jpg', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)">F</a>
```

— Here, it's OK
http://www.les-craneuses.fr/veux-tu-etre-mon-temoin/

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20%20share_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22http://www.les-craneuses.fr/veux-tu-etre-mon-temoin/%22
```

Returned share_count ...

```
<share_count>3</share_count>
```

— But here, it's not
http://www.les-craneuses.fr/buzz-et-woody-pour-son-bapteme/

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20%20share_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22http://www.les-craneuses.fr/buzz-et-woody-pour-son-bapteme/%22
```

Returned share_count ... and i can certify that url was shared 3 times at least.

```
<share_count>0</share_count>
```

Otherwise, if it can help, i noticed that sometimes the shared picture does not appear the first time, but only after reloading or retrying.

Thanks for your help,
Best regards,
Wil